# Image opacity changing at scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, opacity

How does it work? I can´t fix it. 
at this side you see a image with opacity 1 while scrolling. when you stop scrolling it fades to opacity 0.

http://heydays.no/profile/

how does it work? it is css?

Comment: Are you talking about how the word "HEYDAY" appears only when you're scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the scroll position by

```
$(document).scrollTop()
```

I would call setTimeout on a function that compares the current and the last scrollDown values, and this way I could tell if the body was scrolled in the last second. Implementation details are up to you. :-)

Comment: To make it respond instantly, you can also bind to "mousewheel" and "keydown" events but that might be an overkill for such an easy effect.

Comment: Well first of all, it's `setInterval()` you want, not `setTimeout()`.  Second, running some code every few milliseconds regardless of the user activity is unnecessarily bloated.  It's much easier to bind to the scroll event and only use a timer to figure out when they stop scrolling, which only happens for a few seconds at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/HvuLH/

**HTML:**

```
<h1 id="word">HEYDAY</h1>
<p>a bunch of text</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
#word {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: none;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var stopscroll,
visible = false;

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    clearTimeout(stopscroll);
    stopscroll = setTimeout(onStop, 250);

    if (!visible) {
        $('#word').fadeIn();
        visible = true;
    }
});

var onStop = function () {
    $('#word').fadeOut();
    visible = false;
};
```